# what does the -s option in busybox --install [-s] [DIR] stand for?

Tags: busybox

When typing `busybox --help`, one of the usages is: `busybox --install [-s] [DIR]`. What does the `-s` option stand for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is documented in [the `INSTALL` file in the source code](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/INSTALL?h=1_34_stable#n104):

> Installing busybox consists of creating symlinks (or hardlinks) to the
> busybox binary for each applet enabled in busybox, and making sure
> these symlinks are in the shell's command $PATH. [...] You can also
> configure a standalone install capability into the busybox base
> applet, and then install such links at runtime with one of "busybox
> --install" (for hardlinks) or "busybox --install -s" (for symlinks).

So the `--install` creates links for the applets supported by that build of  `buxybox` in the target directory, and `-s` has it make symbolic links.

```
% busybox --install -s foo
% ll foo    
total 8.0K
lrwxrwxrwx 1 muru muru   16 Nov 30 13:19  acpid -> /usr/bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx 1 muru muru   16 Nov 30 13:19  addgroup -> /usr/bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx 1 muru muru   16 Nov 30 13:19  adduser -> /usr/bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx 1 muru muru   16 Nov 30 13:19  adjtimex -> /usr/bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx 1 muru muru   16 Nov 30 13:19  ar -> /usr/bin/busybox
...
```